# How do you find the next element in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

Given I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="someGenericClass">
   <input name="someGenericName">
   <label>not important</label>
</div>
<div class="someGenericClass">
   <input name="someGenericName">
   <label>not important</label>
</div>
<div class="someGenericClass">
   <input name="someGenericName">
   <label>Text I need to find in my test</label>
</div>
```

How do I find the label text in this case? It has no attribute.
I tried to find the first element, and then the next element, but I am missing something:

```
element(by.name('someGenericName')).element(by.xpath('following::label'));
```

Also tried:

```
 element(by.name('someGenericName')).element(by.xpath('following-sibling::label'));
```

EDIT: The class is not unique. It is used multiple times in the DOM.

What happens if the DOM will change? `element.all` seems like a bad idea then, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

element.all should work fine

```
HTML View

<div id='id1' class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li class="foo">1a</li>
    <li class="baz">1b</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id='id2' class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li class="foo">2a</li>
    <li class="bar">2b</li>
  </ul>
</div>

Code

let foo = element.all(by.css('.parent')).all(by.css('.foo'));
expect(foo.getText()).toEqual(['1a', '2a']);
let baz = element.all(by.css('.parent')).all(by.css('.baz'));
expect(baz.getText()).toEqual(['1b']);
let nonexistent = element.all(by.css('.parent'))
  .all(by.css('.NONEXISTENT'));
expect(nonexistent.getText()).toEqual(['']);

// Or using the shortcut $$() notation instead of element.all(by.css()):

let foo = $$('.parent').$$('.foo');
expect(foo.getText()).toEqual(['1a', '2a']);
let baz = $$('.parent').$$('.baz');
expect(baz.getText()).toEqual(['1b']);
let nonexistent = $$('.parent').$$('.NONEXISTENT');
expect(nonexistent.getText()).toEqual(['']);
```

element.all returns a promise array.
You can iterate array and chain to find the label which is following the input tag.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to protractor. I am getting: TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined. How can I solve it?

Comment: use this `list.get(0).$('label').getText();`

Comment: I am trying to store it in a variable. Will this work?

let list = element.all(by.css('name="someGenericName"'));
this.element= list[0].$(by.css('label'));

Trying this and test fails upon start with the above error.

Comment: element.all(by.css('[name="someGenericName"]'))  is the correct locator [] is missing.